# Gráfico de barras com cores diferentes no ggplot2

Tags: ggplot2, r, gráfico

Tenho um gráfico de barras no R com variação percentual, gostaria que os valores percentuais negativos ficassem de cor vermelha, como nesse exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas meu gráfico está ficando da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código que estou utilizando:

```
library(tidyverse)

dados <- read_delim("~/Downloads/arquivo_geral.csv", 
                    ";", escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)
dados <- dados[,-1]

variacaoCasosnovos <- dados %>% 
  mutate(dif_semanal = c(rep(NA, 7), diff(casosNovos, 7)),
         percentual_dif = dif_semanal / lag(casosNovos, 7)) %>% 
  select("percentual_dif")

dados <- cbind(dados, variacaoCasosnovos)

dados %>% 
  filter(estado == "SP", data > "2020-03-31") %>%
  mutate(cor = as.factor(ifelse(variacaoCasosNovos > 0, yes = 1, no = 0))) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x = data, y = variacaoCasosNovos), na.rm = TRUE, color = "black", fill = "#ADD8E6") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  guides(fill = FALSE) +
  labs(x = "", y = "Variação") +
  ggtitle("Variação inter-semanal de novos casos confirmados - Brasil") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("firebrick", "dodgerblue4"))
```

Base de dados: https://covid.saude.gov.br/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Há duas alterações que precisam ser feitas no código. Ambas na geometria de `col`unas.

1. Incluir dentro do `aes(..., fill = cor)`; e
2. Remover o atributo `fill = "#ADD8E6"`.

O que ocorre é que ao você atribuir um valor ao preenchimento, você "apaga" qualquer determinação que o [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2) possa fazer nesta estética.

Assim temos:

```
dados %>% 
  filter(estado == "SP", data > as.Date("2020-03-31")) %>%
  mutate(cor = as.factor(ifelse(variacaoCasosNovos > 0, yes = 1, no = 0))) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x = data, y = variacaoCasosNovos, fill = cor), 
           na.rm = TRUE, color = "black") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  guides(fill = FALSE) +
  labs(x = "", y = "Variação") +
  ggtitle("Variação inter-semanal de novos casos confirmados - Brasil") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("firebrick", "dodgerblue4"))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]